# ZeroPadding2D pad twices when I set padding to 1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, encoder-decoder

I've just started to learn Tensorflow (2.1.0), Keras (2.3.7) with Python 3.7.7.

I'm trying an encoder-decoder network using VGG16.

I need to Upsample a layer from `(12, 12, ...)` to `(25, 25, ...)` to make `conv7_1` has the same shape as `conv4_3` layer. The layer with the 'problem' is `upsp2`:

```
conv4_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
pool_4 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 12, 12, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
pool_5 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 6, 6, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
upsp1 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 12, 12, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv6_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv6_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv6_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________    
upsp2 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 24, 24, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv7_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 24, 24, 512)       2359808
```

I have tried this:

```
#################################
# Decoder
#################################
#conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides = 2, name = 'conv1')(pool5)

upsp1 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp1')(pool5)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_1')(upsp1)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_2')(conv6)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_3')(conv6)

zero1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding = (1,1), data_format = 'channels_last', name='zero1')(conv6)
upsp2 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp2')(zero1)
```

But I get that shape `(12, 12, ...)` gets into `(14, 14, ...)` at `zero1` layer:

```
conv6_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
zero1 (ZeroPadding2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
upsp2 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 28, 28, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
```

How can I upsample `(12,12,512)` to `(25,25,512)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using padding as a tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints: interpreted as ((top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad)). And setting `ZeroPadding2D` at the end of convolution 7 layer:

```
#################################
# Decoder
#################################
#conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides = 2, name = 'conv1')(pool5)

upsp1 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp1')(pool5)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_1')(upsp1)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_2')(conv6)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_3')(conv6)

upsp2 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp2')(conv6)
conv7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv7_1')(upsp2)
conv7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv7_2')(conv7)
conv7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv7_3')(conv7)
zero1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding =  ((1, 0), (1, 0)), data_format = 'channels_last', name='zero1')(conv7)
```